# error fetching status of docusign envelope - account IDs muddled?

Tags: docusignapi

I have set up an integrator key and am happily sending envelopes via REST API ; all seems to be working.

But when I try to fetch the status of an envelope some time later I get:

```
{"errorCode":"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."}
```

I'm hoping this is because the integrator key is still in demo status but am just a bit nervous I've misunderstood the various account IDs.

The account ID returned from https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo using the oAuth token turns out to be my `API account ID` and its that I'm passing in the url, i.e.:

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountid}/envelopes/status.

In the real world this application (a `win32 .exe`) will be logging in (via oAuth) to the various docusign accounts belonging to my customers, so I would have expected '../userinfo' to be returning the customer's "User ID" instead? Or am i supposed to get that direct from the customer themselves?

The integrator key is set to "Authorization Code Grant".

Comment: how do you obtain a token?

Comment: this message says you didn't specify a key at all

Comment: the message is from the /envelopes/status call and i don;t see a requirement to include the integration key except in that it is used to get the oAuth token.The oAUth token was fetched using  "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token"

Comment: it's used to get a token. How did you obtain the token?

Comment: this was the auth endpoint: "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth" and specifying my client id and client secret.

Comment: and when you logged in you used the same account that owns the envelopeID you later used?

Comment: please read above. I used the same account to fetch the status as i used to create the envelope.

Comment: send me an email, I'll help you privately. Clearly, something is not as it seems, but I can't help you here without getting into all the details about your account .
In your email to inbar.gazit@docusign.com please include your account number and clientID

Comment: email sent;  but i  have to type a min of 15 chars here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was indeed that the token was missing from the subsequent call to get the envelope status. and that was because of chilkat's httpreq object requiring the token header added rather than the http object. My confusion over account IDs was ill founded. It is the API Account ID as returned by /userinfo that is required in subsequent calls.